# Rotating and balancing HingeJoint2D with mouse drag

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to implement physics, similar to this game:

https://sites.google.com/site/newstudyhall/games/tilt-2

I have a “Hand” sprite, which is Kinematic and have a HingeJoint2D on it. Another sprite “Stick”, which is not Kinematic, is connected to hand through HingeJoint2D. I want to balance the Stick on hand by moving the hand.

I have attached following script with hand. I am moving the hand with mouse drag and applying force on stick in opposite direction of mouse movement. But it is not working as in above mentioned game.

Is there any component in Unity, which I can use to produce this result or how can I implement it?

```
private Vector3 screenPoint;
private Vector3 offset;


void FixedUpdate()
{
    //ON CLICK
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10));

    }

    //ON DRAG
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10);

        //HAND POSITION CHANGE WITH MOUSE DRAG
        Vector2 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPoint) + offset;
        transform.position = cursorPosition;

        //APPLY FORCE ON TRAY IN OPPOSITE DIRECTION OF MOUSE MOVEMENT
        GameObject.Find("Stick").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(((cursorPosition.normalized * 5)) * -1, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use rigidbody2d components and the gravity parameter to do balacing like that in a very simple way.

[Here is a link to a similar question with a very good answer that may help you](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/364685/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-balance-board.html)

Comment: I see that you are already using rigidbodies, I think you just need to use the gravity setting already avaliable, although you may need to customize it a bit to get the desired balacing effect for the game.